# NodeJS - Missing key in JSON during rejecting Promises

Tags: json, node.js, promise, mocha.js, assert

I'm trying to create a unit tests for my function I faced with issue reading data from JSON body of rejected promise.

Inside the function I have:

```
`return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
               .....
                return reject({
                    'code': ID_NOT_VALID,
                    'message': 'Required header has invalid value'
                })`
```

And in my test I'm doing next:

```
 const errJson = {
        code: ID_NOT_VALID,
        message: 'Required header has invalid value'
    };
......

it('should not be empty', async () => {
        return assert.isRejected(validate.validateCorrelationId(), errJson, errJson);
    });
```

As result, I found that for some reason response contains ONLY "message" parameters, and not the "code" and not in JSON format.

```
AssertionError: expected promise to be rejected with an error including { Object (code, message) } but got 'Required header has invalid value'
```

Looks like for some reason ANY other key is ignored but "message". What am I doing wrong? How to return and validate JSON as part of Promise reject?

The full code is below:

1. Function:

> ```
> exports.validate = (strId) => {
>   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
>     if (!strId) {
>         return reject({
>             'code': constants.ID_NOT_VALID,
>             'message': 'Required header is not present in request'
>         });...........
> ```

2. Test:

> `const chai = require('chai');`

```
    const chaiAsPromised = require("chai-as-promised");
     const expect = chai.expect;
     const assert = chai.assert;
     chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
```

> ```
> describe('validate', () => {
> const errJson = {
>     'code': constants.ID_NOT_VALID,
>     'message':'Required header has invalid value'
> };
>
> it('should not be empty', async () => {
>     return assert.isRejected(validate.validateCorrelationId(), errJson, errJson);
> });......
> ```

// Next test works:

> ```
> it('should be valid ID', async () => {
>         const result = await validate.validate('352d-11e8');
>         expect(result).to.equal('352d-11e8');
>     });
> ```

Comment: Not enough code here for us to follow the flow and understand what's going on.

Comment: Do you realize that in this statement `const res = validate.validateCorrelationId().catch(() => {});`, `res` is going to be a promise?  You will have to use `.then()` or `await` on it to get the value out of it.

Comment: Plus, `.catch(() => {});` wipes out any error you had previously and replaces it with an empty object.

Comment: Thank you @jfriend00, removed unused code from the test above, I'm using "chai-as-promised" example provided at https://www.npmjs.com/package/chai-as-promised (return assert.isRejected(promise, "optional message");)